# Why $\{\omega :[0,1]\to \mathbb R\text{ continuous}\}$. is not in $\sigma \{(\omega :[0,1]\to \mathbb R\mid \omega (t_i)\in B_i\}$.?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

For $B\in \mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ (the borel $\sigma -$algebra), we denote $C_t(B):=\{\omega :[0,1]\to \mathbb R\mid \omega (t)\in B\}$. Let $$\mathcal F=\sigma \{C_t(B)\mid t\in [0,1], B\in \mathcal B(\mathbb R)\}.$$

Why $\mathcal A:=\{\omega :[0,1]\to \mathbb R\text{ continuous}\}$ do not belong to $\mathcal F$ ?

I think that I have to prove that there are no countable collection of $\{B_i\}\subset \mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ and $\{t_i\}$ s.t. $$\mathcal A=\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty C_{t_i}(B_i),$$
but I don't know how to do it. I tried by contradiction, i.e. I suppose that $$\mathcal A=\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty C_{t_i}(B_i),$$
but I don't know what to do...

Comment: RHS is not contained in LHS. Take any $\omega$ in RHS and change the value at one point $t \in [0,1]\setminus \{t_i\}_i$ so as to make $\omega$ dis-continuous

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand. Can you elaborate a bit ?@KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: Looks to me that all elements of elements of $\mathcal{F}$ visit $B$ at some time. But unless $B=\mathbb{R}$, there is some $y \in \mathbb{R} \setminus B$ and then $\omega \equiv y$ will not be in any element of $\mathcal{F}$.

Comment: Though considering what saz chose as a duplicate, I suspect my example isn't the point, since you probably meant to allow $B$ to vary in $\mathcal{B}$, so that this would be the cylindric $\sigma$-algebra.